# Regex match multiple Group.Captures with multiline

Tags: c#, regex, multilinestring

I want get all captures from group by 5 lines + empty line between each capture.
I was trying that way, but receive only first capture. When I deleting first capture from test string I receive next capture and so on, so seems my regexp is right to match.
What am I missed?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        var strBackups = @"wbadmin 1.0 - Backup command-line tool
(C) Copyright 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Backup time: 01.09.2015 11:51 
Backup target: 1394/USB Disk labeled BIGGER2(F:)
Version identifier: 09/01/2015-06:51
Can recover: Volume(s), File(s), Application(s), Bare Metal Recovery, System State
Snapshot ID: {060e3b44-7b80-49bf-97c4-3f3b9908dec6}

Backup time: 06.09.2015 10:36 
Backup target: 1394/USB Disk labeled BIGGER2(F:)
Version identifier: 09/06/2015-05:36
Can recover: Volume(s), File(s), Application(s), Bare Metal Recovery, System State
Snapshot ID: {64af3693-362d-42dc-ae5f-566b3f2d40be}

Backup time: 06.09.2015 11:00 
Backup target: 1394/USB Disk labeled BIGGER2(F:)
Version identifier: 09/06/2015-06:00
Can recover: Volume(s), File(s), Application(s), Bare Metal Recovery, System State
Snapshot ID: {d9d50a01-6907-40a1-9c57-1f45de76b9ec}

";

        var regBackups = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(".+\r\n.+\r\n\r\n(.+\r\n.+\r\n.+\r\n.+\r\n.+\r\n)+",
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compiled | System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline
        );

        var match = regBackups.Match(strBackups);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            for (var i = 1; i < match.Groups.Count; i++)
            {
                foreach (var c in match.Groups[i].Captures)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("=============================");
                    Console.WriteLine(c);
                    Console.WriteLine("=============================");
                }
            }
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("<not matched>");
    }
```

Sorry for broken format by multiline strings

Code looks like that without broke formatting:
[image: Code]

Comment: 1) Your regex above can be shortened as `(?:.+\r\n){2}\r\n((?:.+\r\n){5})+`. 2) Your regex currently [returns 2 matches](http://goo.gl/LaLu7P), 3) You get 1 match only because you use `Regex.Match`, not `Regex.Matches`. `match = match.NextMatch();` and `while` handle this well, see [demo](http://ideone.com/JbMwwm). No idea if you really need this output, or if you still need an answer for this question. If you do, please review my comment, and let me know what you need.

Answer (score 0):

#### Split

If you don't need to validate there are 5 consecutive lines, you could simply split by empty lines:

```
var regBackups = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(?:\r\n){2}");
var result = regBackups.Split(strBackups);

foreach (var c in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("=============================");
    Console.WriteLine(c);
    Console.WriteLine("=============================");
}
```

This is by far the preferred option.
[Example](http://ideone.com/dLkztY)

#### Match

If you must validate that the text blocks have 5 consecutive lines, you can use the following approach:

```
var regBackups = new Regex(@"\r\n((?>\r\n.+){5})(?!\r\n.)",
    RegexOptions.Compiled
);

foreach (Match m in regBackups.Matches(strBackups))
{
    Console.WriteLine("=============================");
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("=============================");
}
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/ThjCZX)
The expression `\r\n((?>\r\n.+){5})(?!\r\n.)` matches:

1. `\r\n` a cr+lf, followed by
2. `\r\n.+` a cr+lf and a line with at least 1 character.
3. The `(?>  ...  ){5}` is to repeat the previous 5 times. It's an atomic group (more efficient in this case) with the quantifier at the end.
4. `(?!\r\n.)` not followed by a cr+lf and a character (ie. not followed by another line).